# How do I clean up the Video Sequencer background in Blender 3.4.1

Tags: blender

With Blender 3.4.1, the editor type Video Sequencer with type Sequencer displays an area filled with digital garbage.

I am running on Debian 12 with a Plasma desktop, although I have also tried this on a Gnome desktop with the same results.

I have uninstalled Blender, wiped out the ~/.config/blender directory and reinstalled Blender via the command line - `apt install blender`.

I have tried this with various combinations of spash-screen and work spaces, all without any change.